# How to add column to as specific position in a ListView?

Tags: c#, listview

Is there a way to add a column to a specific position in a ListView?

So far I add it normally, so it appears at the end, then I move it using this code:

[I want to change order of colums of listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17746013/i-want-to-change-order-of-colums-of-listview)

However it takes 2 steps. Is there a way to directly add it to a given position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [insert method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsdc2y8c(v=vs.110).aspx) that you can call to insert the column into the position you'd like.